# Deleting elements dequeued using "top" from priority_queue c++

Tags: c++

I have a priority queue of objects called Events. The Event objects all have Cell's in them, that are created using "new". I know since I use "new" I need to delete the Cell inside the object, but I'm not sure how. I get the event from the queue using top, and then later I pop the event to remove it from the queue. I'm worried if I delete it before I call "pop" I will have an inconsistent queue since I never officially popped it. If I try to delete it after, I'm afraid I won't have a reference to it. How can I properly delete this memory?

Thanks in advance!

```
priority_queue<Event, vector<Event>, CompareEvent> events;
Event *firstEvent = new Event(*start, time);
events.push(*firstEvent); //Add first event to queue

while (!(events.empty())){

    //Get next event
    currentEvent = events.top();
    // if some condition, add another event 
        newEvent1 = new Event(*daughterCell, time, newDir);
        events.push(*newEvent1);
    events.pop();
```

The Event constructor:

```
Event::Event()
{
    //Cell currentCell;
    //int timePoint = rand() % 6 + 5;
    currentCell = new Cell();
    timePoint = rand() % 6 + 5;
}
```

Comment: Creating a `new Event` and storing `*event` is a memory leak, omit that new!

Comment: @DieterLücking I admit that even I'm guilty of doing that! This will result in the compiler throwing an error (depending on the warning level). I believe a simple `delete` gets rid of the leak when you're done with it.

Answer (score 1):

The only satisfying solution is using [std::unique_ptr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/unique_ptr/) or [std::shared_ptr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/).

You should anyway always try to avoid using a raw *new*, using smart pointers gives you exception safety and no memory leaks. The overhead for *unique_ptr* is almost non-existent, *shared_ptr* takes a bit more, but you get copy functionality.

With C++14 you should use [std::make_shared](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/make_shared/) or [std::make_unique](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique).

---

**Edit:**

However, you don't need dynamically allocated memory (coming from Java?).
Just create your objects on the stack (without *new*). Then you don't have to delete manually (or with RAII).

Comment: Of course, but the questioner asked for a solution for his specific problem and thats the easiest way I know to accomplish that.

Comment: OP doesn't need pointers. Look at the type of the priority queue.

Comment: He asked how he could properly delete the allocated memory, I gave him the answer. But you are right as he is dereferencing the pointer he does not really need it. (saw ur edit too late)

Comment: The answer is not to allocate dynamically.

Comment: Yes coming from Java and C#... ugh haha

Answer (score 1):

You are allocating an instance of `Event` on the heap, thus obtaining a pointer to that instance, but you then decide to pass that instance *by value* to your priority queue. To deallocate a heap allocated instance, use the `delete` operator.

```
priority_queue<Event, vector<Event>, CompareEvent> events;
Event *firstEvent = new Event(*start, time);
events.push(*firstEvent); //Add first event to queue
delete FirstEvent;  // free that instance up
```

You might want to instead use a local variable:

```
priority_queue<Event, vector<Event>, CompareEvent> events;
Event firstEvent (*start, time);
events.push(*firstEvent); //Add first event to 
// no delete necessary
```

Or make the queue store pointers to instances:

```
priority_queue<Event*, vector<Event*>, CompareEvent> events;
Event *firstEvent = new Event(*start, time);
events.push(firstEvent); // no dereferencing
```

But you'll still have to manage instances lifetime by hand, using `delete` appropriately (this can be mitigated with `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr`).

Alternatively, you could also use the `emplace`  method to construct the instance directly in the queue:

```
priority_queue<Event, vector<Event>, CompareEvent> events;
events.emplace(*start, time); // no temporary variable needed.
```

Comment: Thank you! I've switched the Event object to be not a pointer in the first place and that seems to have helped.